# Big Number,input char[]

Tags: c++

I have problem with the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[200];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; cin.get() != '\n'; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << i;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why when i input without space 10 char for example. i si equal to 10/2=5 ?

Comment: When you do cin.get() you get one char. Next, when you do cin >> you get second char. But only the second one you insert in table a.

Comment: yes but only after i input all the characters i cin>>ENTER.So only the last a[i] shouldnt be inputted ?

Comment: Add `#include <cstdlib>` to use `system` function, or delete `system("pause");`.

Comment: nothing changed MikeCAT

Comment: Two months old question, no upvote, no accepted answer, no edit. I'm voting to close this question as **unclear what you're asking**.

Answer (score 0):

You discard every odd symbol, `cin.get()` read symbol 1,
`cin >>` read symbol two, and again `cin.get()` read symbol 3,
and `cin >>` read symbol 4 from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

You get two characters, once increment i variable and only second of them insert in array

```
int main()
{
    char a[200];
    int i;
    \\ cin.get() - get one char and insert it in a[i]
    \\ after that, compare this value with '\n'
    \\ if equal, break the loop, if different, continue
    for (i = 0; (a[i] = cin.get()) != '\n'; i++);
    \\ last character ('\n') should be replaced with '\0'
    a[i]='\0';
    cout << i;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

while solution:

```
int main()
{
    char a[200];
    int i=0;
    cin >> a[i];
    while (a[i] != '\n')
    {
      i++;
      cin >> a[i];
    }

    a[i]='\0';
    cout << i;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

do - while solution:

```
int main()
{
    char a[200];
    int i=0;
    do
    {
      cin >> a[i];
    }
    while(a[i++]!='\n');

    a[i-1]='\0';
    cout << i-1;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks correct; adding an explanation will attract upvotes.

Comment: @gprex read about for loop. Before iteration loop check condition, in your example: get.cin() != '\n' . So you get one char from input and chech if it was enter. Otherwise the loop gets inside, so you get cin >> a[i], so you get second char from input. And after that, the i value increments (only once). You get two chars and only one incrementation of i. Do you understand?

Comment: @gprex ok, the main think is that cin.get() and cin >> a[i] works the same. Both of them gets char from input. Is that clear?

Comment: i understood why my program is not working...I cant understand yours

Comment: i add comments. The main difference is that in my code is only one get from input and, in the same instruction, insert in array.

Comment: my god....i do the same thing.....i complare it with '\n'. You do the same thing ...... ;(

Comment: @gprex yes, but you compare with '\n' one char and by cin >> a[i] get from input another. I'm over. I'm sorry buy my patience is not as big. Good luck.

Comment: It was going to be really good, if you could change you code, so i can understand it easily. I am in the beginning so i think like that for(;;){ action}

Comment: yes, in my code you've got for(;;);. The semicolon means empty action. Whole action is done in condition.

Comment: i got this now... so if i dont want to lose information. and in the for() i have cin.get, i should put the action in the condition ?

Comment: yes, because cin.get already get an char from input. Better solution there is use while loop

Comment: Finally!After almost 3 hours, headache, i got it .Thank you, man ! If you have time could you write the "while" solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing out half of your `cin` results.

When you use `cin`, a character is read, but you are not assigning it to anything inside the `for` loop criteria; only inside the loop body are you saving it.

Inside the loop, you read in *another* character (after the one you already read in during the loop's test criteria) and assign *that* one. The loop repeats, and the *next* character read is again thrown away with the line `cin.get() != '\n'` because you are not assigning the results to anything. And this continues, alternating characters you throw away with characters you "save" into the array.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, you are reading the standard input (`std::cin`) in two different ways, storing its output only once every two character extractions.

[`std::basic_istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (`cin.get()`) extracts character or characters from stream. Once extracted, whey are forgotten, sent to limbo. You simply ignore them. Which is not what I suspect you want to do.

[`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) (`cin >> ...`) also extracts character or characters (following the type of the right hand side operand).

So, with an input of ten characters, you ignore five of them in your `for` condition check and store five in the loop block.

A correct way to read the characters would be to use `std::getline` (en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string input;
std::getline(cin, input);
std::cout << input << std::endl;
```

This example code will simply read a line and output it, verbatim, in the standart output.